# Retrieve data from resultSet into textfields

Tags: java, sql, database, user-interface, rmi

So I have a string method that takes a string parameter. I am trying to pass a string to the method via a textfield(easy part) and perform an SQL query on that passed parameter. It's an RMI application and this method's job is to retrieve details about an item.

```
public String SearchItem(String item) throws RemoteException {

    String olo1 = "Select * from StockTB where ItemName ='" + item + "';";
    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();

    try{
        Statement statement = link.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery(olo1);

        while(results.next()){
            System.out.println("Item_ID:" + results.getInt(1));
            System.out.println("Item Name:" + results.getString(2));
            System.out.println("Description:" + results.getString(3));
            System.out.println("Price:" + results.getString(4));
            System.out.println("Stock Amount:" + results.getString(5));
            System.out.println("Item found!");
            return("Item found!");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: Error retrieving data!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
        link.close();
    }
    catch(SQLException e1){
        System.out.print("Error: Unable to disconnect!");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Item not found!");
    return("Not found");
}
```

and this is my button code in another class.

```
JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try{
            Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("192.168.0.10",1099);
            db123 = (DBService)Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost/DBService");
            String tt2 = db123.SearchItem(textField1.getText());

            if(tt2 != null){
                //tt2.
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,textField1.getText() +  " Item not found! Please search for another item.");
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception e1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1);
        }
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is enter an item via the first textfield in my GUI and return the results into the subsequent textfields. I'm stumped. I've been looking at resultSet objects but can't figure it out. Just looking to get ideas.

[image: GUI]

Comment: Suppose your search finds 42 items. How do you plan to show these 42 items, each having an ID, a name, etc., into those 5 text fields? Why does your method return a String, rather than a List<Item>?

Comment: I'll look into using list. But if I search for kettle it should return the five detail fields associated with kettle.

Comment: Then don't return a List<Item>, but an Item instead. And don't use `while (results.next())`, but `if (results.next())`, since the query is supposed to retrieve at most one row.Transform that row into an Item instance, and return that Item.

Comment: You should also revise your code in general. Use a PreparedStatement and don't just build the query by concatenation to prevent SQL injection. Move `link.close()` to a finally block so that it is invoked even if you exit your method early. Don't use `System.exit()` - send useful information about the error back to the client. And last but not least, use a logging framework instead of just printing to `System.out` and `System.err`.

Comment: Ok will look into all these things. Any standards for a logging framework?